# Building Qt statically (regarding configure -static additional options)

Tags: qt, static, qt-creator

So I see the tutorial on how to build Qt statically, however I have a question. If I were using QMYSQL drivers in my program what would I need to add to `configure -static`? would  -singleexec do the trick?

Link to tutorial: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/deployment-windows.html#linking-the-application-to-the-static-version-of-qt

Options: http://radekp.github.io/qtmoko/api/buildsystem/over-configure-options-1.html

What I want is a standalone.

Comment: Please **don't** Google for random documentation sources. That qtmoko page still has Trolltech copyrights on it! Use only the official documentation on http://qt-project.org/doc/ (or, better, the source :-)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configure script supports building additional SQL drivers into QtSql itself; try passing `-qt-sql-mysql` to it (together with `-static`). You also need to pass all the `-I`, `-L` and eventually `-l` options to be able to build the MySQL driver (the compiler and the linker must be able to find your MySQL include files and libraries; so, unless they're in "standard paths", you need to add those flags to make the MySQL driver compile).

---

If that doesn't work, you can always build the MySQL driver as a *static plugin* -- just follow the ordinary build instructions to build the driver (after you built Qt statically by means of `configure -static`), it will produce a static plugin. You then need to

1. add `QTPLUGIN += qsqlmysql` in your .pro file
2. add `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(qsqlmysql)` somewhere in your app (like, around main).

See the [docs about static plugins](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins) for more information about this.

Comment: So if i've installed QMYSQL drivers already (able to connect to mysql database) would i need to type `-qt-sql-mysql` after configure -static? Also, I don't quite get what you mean by adding `-I`, `-L`, and `-l` options. If I use the 2nd option, I'll just need to add steps 1 and 2, and then run `configure -static` ?

Comment: I've elaborated in my answer.

Comment: If I have mysql server installed in `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL` what would I type with `-I`, `-L`, `-l`? The documents say `-I` for include path, `-L` for library path, but what of `-l`? So would I type `-I C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib`. I'm lost with `-l` though. Do I need to pass `-I` etc together with `-static`? or after?

Comment: As I said, `-l` shouldn't be needed. Just pass `-I` and `-L` as configure options. Preventing a future question, may I suggest you to reinstall MySQL in a path *without any spaces*? :-)

Comment: That error has nothing to do with this problem. You need OpenGL headers (and pass `-opengl`) or the DirectX SDK installed.

Comment: http://puu.sh/3stbx.png I get those errors near the bottom :/. I ran `configure -static -I C:\PROGRA~2\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.5\include -L C:\PROGRA~2\MySQL\MYSQLS~1.5\lib\` And I'm not sure if you know but i DID install QMYSQL drivers already (before trying to build statically)

Comment: Wait, is that Qt 5.0?! That doesn't support static linking -- try 5.1 (RC2 available on http://download.qt-project.org/snapshots/qt/5.1/5.1.0-rc2/ )

Comment: I somehow got it to work? I'm running mingwmake now. And where did you get 5.1? :O I only see 5.0.2 from this site http://qt-project.org/downloads#qt-creator I know oyu linked me, im just curious as to how you know theres 5.1

Comment: Which doesn't change what I said: 5.0 does not support static linking. Since you didn't state the Qt version in your post, and the question wasn't tagged qt5, and you linked to Qt 4 documentation, I assumed Qt 4. Try using 5.1.

Comment: I got http://puu.sh/3sRAx.png this error where I run mingw32-make after this command `configure -static -I C:\MySql\Include -L C:\MySql\lib`

Comment: Looks like Python is missing. Is it the case?

Comment: I have python installed but not in qtbase. do i need 2.7?

Comment: I installed it in C:\Qt\Qt5.1.0\Source but it still gives me that error =/

Comment: @peppe, what am I looking for (extension-wise) in both the include location and the lib locations? I'm trying to build a static MS SQL library (i have a shared plugin version that came installed by the Qt Creator + Source installer)

Comment: What do you mean, "extension wise"? For MS SQL you'd need to compile the ODBC driver coming with Qt. In order to do that, Qt needs to find and link against an ODBC implementation, and that's what those `-I` and `-L` paths should point to (for headers and libraries respectively). Try looking for the paths containing `sql.h`, `sqlext.h` and friends, and the path containing `odbc32.lib`.